# What are the Intrinsic properties of Euclidean spaces?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading  a book "An introduction  to Manifold "by Loring W.Tu . I am not understand  this line "euclidean spaces are  handicap because,  defined in terms of coordinates, it is often not obvious which concepts are intrinsic, i.e., independent of coordinates"  I am not understand  which concept  are intrinsic. ..Please  any one help me to understand  these line ..and explain in easy way

Answer (score 0):

The Euclidean metric and many of its properties are ``intrinsic''. 
 For example, for any two distinct points $x$ and $y$, there is a unique point $z$ such that $d(x,z)=d(z,y)=d(x,y)/2$.  All the properties of lines you learned in high school (such as, two distinct lines cannot intersect in exactly 2 points) are intrinsic properties.